# Build and Compile PJSIP For Desktop Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, sip, pjsip

How to build and compile PJSIP for desktop Mac?
I have done with iPhone/iPad. But still have an issue, so now I want to try to build in a desktop Mac version.

I followed [this link](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Autoconf), honestly i dont understand at all how to use it. Because it's different for what I have done in mobile.

Any clue? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For iphone you had to define the PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE to your config:

```
#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1
```

This part is not needed anymore.
Then you had to call ./configure-iphone 
for mac you just have to call ./configure and in the rest is like any other package compilation and installation on linux and unix environment:

```
# ./configure
# make dep
# make
# make install
```

Comment: how about the openSSL? it installed automatically? I did it, but still can't adding an account. The TLS connection closed.

Comment: I still have :  
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [../bin/pjlib-test-x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pjlib-test-x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0] Error 2

Comment: you get this error for mac version or for iphone version?

Comment: @alinoz `This part is not needed anymore` -> Could you elaborate on that? Are you talking about building for iOS or macOS here? If you're referring to building for iOS, would you be so kind and show that there's any evidence? It's not clear whether this sentence refers to building pjsip in general: _For iphone you __had__ to define_ (what does that mean?) or for MacOS.

Comment: ./configure was throwing the same error for me too , try with ./configure --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-memalign-hack , tis one worked on Mac @NikolaLukic